# How to destroy a database record if it fails uniqueness validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to be able to destroy a database record if it fails a uniqueness validation when updating its attributes. For example, if I try to update a record's field to another value which has a uniqueness validation and already exists in another record in the database, the original object that is being updated should be destroyed.

I have tried using the `after_validation` callback to call a function that destroys the object, however, ActiveRecord keeps rolling back and returning false, and I don't know why. I think it may have something to do with the uniqueness validation, however, am not sure.

I am using Rails 5 and ActiveRecord to interact with the database.

Below is an example:

```
class Question
 validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

 after_validation :destroy

 def destroy
  if self.errors.any?
   self.destroy
  end
 end
```

The validation is only on one field of the object

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it at the model level, but how about the controller level? `record.destroy if ! record.save`

Comment: I wouldn't give your custom function the same name as the ActiveRecord method: try renaming it to `destroy_if_invalid` maybe?

Comment: @CarlMarkham That would definitely work, but I would like to try and keep it in a callback if I can, otherwise I will have to do that check every time I update the attributes of that kind of object, and that would be a lot of repetitive code. If i can't figure it out, I think this is the best approach

Comment: @rwold That a good idea. It didn't solve the problem, but is good coding style

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen I can't really help without writing some example code to test so I'm out. But if repetition is the issue, you could always add a helper method `destroy_if_not_unique!` which would call my above example

Comment: @CarlMakham Good idea!

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to get something working before making it perfect. If you are stuck on the perfect solution, just make it work as best you can. Later on, you may find the solution and be able to replace your code

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen I'd make a stronger statement than that: normally, this mistake would lead to `StackTooDeep` exception due to an infinite loop! With Rails' dynamic metaprogramming all bets are off, but I can't imagine anything good happening...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this in controller layer

example_controller.rb

```
def update
  if @question.update(params.require(:question).permit(:name))
     ...
  else
    @question.destroy if @question.errors.added?(:name, : uniqueness)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to check how many questions in a delete method before call destroy:

```
def delete
  if Question.where(name: self.name).count > 1
    self.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: OP want's the validations to happen and only destroy if they fail. Your code will bypass all validations

Comment: @CarlMarkham could you please check my answer now? And if it's the case, remove your -1 vote. Thank you.

Comment: I checked when you edited it. OP wants to use validations, your answer doesn't use validations and adds an extra method which is not ideal

Comment: @CarlMarkham sure, but it's a way to solve the problem, and it's his project, so he is the one who can decide if it's "ideal" or not for this situation. Sorry if you don't like my answer, I agree that it does not cover all points, but it's a start, and your down vote seems exaggerated now.